# Get correlation per groupby/apply in Python Polars

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, python-polars, pandas-apply

I have a pandas DataFrame `df`:

```
d = {'era': ["a", "a", "b","b","c", "c"], 'feature1': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 'feature2': [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], 'target': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

And I want to apply a correlation between the `feature_cols = ['feature1', 'feature2']` and the `TARGET_COL = 'target'` for each `era`:

```
corrs_split = (
          training_data
          .groupby("era")
          .apply(lambda d: d[feature_cols].corrwith(d[TARGET_COL]))
)
```

I've been trying to get this done with Polars, but I can't get a polars dataframe with a column for each different `era` and the correlations for each `feature`. The maximum I've got, is a single column, with all the correlations calculated, but without the `era` as index and not discriminated by `feature`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the polars equivalent of that code. You can do this by combining `group_by()` and `agg()`.

```py
import polars as pl

d = {'era': ["a", "a", "b","b","c", "c"], 'feature1': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 'feature2': [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], 'target': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,6]}
df = pl.DataFrame(d)
feature_cols = ['feature1', 'feature2']
TARGET_COL = 'target'

agg_cols = []
for feature_col in feature_cols:
    agg_cols += [pl.corr(feature_col, TARGET_COL)]
print(df.group_by("era").agg(agg_cols))
```

Output:

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ era ┆ feature1 ┆ feature2 │
│ --- ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ str ┆ f64      ┆ f64      │
╞═════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ c   ┆ 1.0      ┆ 1.0      │
│ b   ┆ 1.0      ┆ 1.0      │
│ a   ┆ 1.0      ┆ 1.0      │
└─────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

(Order may be different for you.)

Comment: Thank you. But the output is something strange (even after changing each era to have at least 2 samples): `[<polars.internals.expr.expr.Expr at 0x7fb5ee114220>,
 <polars.internals.expr.expr.Expr at 0x7fb5ee1141c0>]`

Comment: @jbssm I can't reproduce this for the example you posted in Polars 0.15.1. Can you post an example which triggers this issue, or post the version of polars if it's a version dependent issue?

Comment: Never mind, discard my comment, it was my error. Thank you, this works nicely! (I was doing an extra `groupby` in my code and hence the error).

Comment: With v0.18.4 of polars results in `AttributeError: module 'polars' has no attribute 'pearson_corr'`. Need to update `pl.pearson_corr` to `pl.corr`.